# Is it valid to "hide" a base class virtual function by making it pure virtual in derived classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider the example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    virtual void f();
};

void A::f()
{
    std::cout << "f() from A\n";
}

class B: public A {
    public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class C: public B {
    public:
    void f();
};

void C::f()
{
    std::cout << "f() from C\n";
}

int main()
{
    C o;
    o.f();
}
```

`A::f()` implementation is "hidden" from class C, which provides its own implementation for `f()` - effectively making `A::f()` more or less pointless. I see little value in such class hierarchy design, but my question whether this is a valid C++ or just "works" (such as undefined behaviours)?

Comment: Though it's "hidden" you can still use `A::f()` to call `A`'s implementation (for example : `o.A::f();`).

Comment: Consider using `override` when overriding a base class' `virtual` member function to avoid errors.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I understand `A::f()` can be called directly. I just wondered if this is a valid thing. Thanks for the `override` suggestion which I often forget!

Comment: One possibility would be that `C::f()` could delegate part of its implementation to `A::f()` again.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is clearly allowed and supported by the standard (cf, for example, [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.abstract#5) online C++ standard draft), and thus clearly not undefined behaviour:

> **10.4 Abstract classes**
>
> 5 [ Note: An abstract class can be derived from a class that is not
>   abstract, and a pure virtual function may override a virtual function
>   which is not pure.  — end note ]

The effect is that your class `B` becomes abstract and any subclass - if it shall not be abstract, too - must define `f()` then; the implementation in class `A` can still be invoked through `A::f()`, such that it is - from the perspective of reusing the implementation - not pointless.

Answer (score 3):

This will safely achieve the goal of requiring the author of `C` to provide an implementation for `f()`.

I would query why this is needed — if the base implementation is not "valid" in your design then why does it exist, and/or why is it `virtual`?

They can still invoke `A::f()`, anyway, so whether this can be deemed "hiding" is open to debate.

Comment: It's unclear what the OP thinks is being hidden. Seems quite clear what it does and I don't see anything being hidden.

Comment: I agree with your question - but a colleague argued this increases "safety" (i.e., it forces C to provide an implementation and avoids calling A::f() accidentally while allowing A::f() to be called directly if needed). bTW, the "hidden" is used for want of a better word. Hiding isn't really important to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @doug It hides "the ability of the non-pureness of `A::f()` to allow people not to bother overriding `f()`", I guess.

Comment: @usr: I can sort of get behind that, _if_ it is dangerous/undesirable for someone to forget to override `f()`. But then it should be pure virtual in the base already, no?

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable for a base to provide a default implementation and it is perfectly reasonable for a derived to realize that the default implementation is contextually incorrect and further inheritors must write a correct one.  Off the head instance:  when layering an abstract logging system over an existing concrete error reporting object hierarchy, abstract loggers may not want to spew their logging content to stderr, but do need to store their content somewhere.  (It's a mandatory 3rd part error reporter, so refactoring it is not going to happen.)

Comment: So the point of the technique is to force classes derived from B to require an f() so it flags, at compile time, the lack of a definition. It wasn't clear to me why the OP's code would produce UB. It's quite well defined and may be of some use. Almost all of my limited OOP used pure virtual base classes and rarely had multiple levels below that.  The notion of forcing definitions in subclasses where a superclass provides a definition is interesting.

Comment: If you can't modify `A` then sure.

Answer (score 2):

> my question whether this is a valid C++ or just "works" (such as undefined behaviours)?

The behaviour of the program is well defined.

> effectively making `A::f()` more or less pointless.

Of course, if you never call a function, then defining the function is unnecessary indeed. To clarify, the function would have to be declared pure virtual if you did choose to omit the definition (the opposite is not true; you *can* define a pure virtual function).

Answer (score 2):

This is valid and well-defined C++.

It can occasionally be useful if you want to force a user of your class to implement a method that's already implemented in a base class (and don't want to use a different name which would be a more obvious choice). GUI libraries implementing operating system message pumps are one application.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see there's no undefined behavior = 0 only means that derived classes must override it. But you can still provide an out-of-line definition for that function in the same class.